# How to add chromedriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I haven't figured out how to install Chrome Driver for about 8 hours. I've done a lot of research and I've never tried one.
Here is the contents of my Deployment package file: http://prntscr.com/o4kcjw
I got quite a lot of errors when I tried it through the serverless CLI. How can I solve this problem?

I create and assign selenium, pymsql and chromedriver to Lambda with virtualenv. (Zipped)
I have a python file inside my zipped file.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=960x900')

# Define browser driver
chrome_driver = '/chromedriver-Linux64.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

> {   "errorMessage": "Message: 'chromedriver-Linux64.exe' executable
>   needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home\n",
>   "errorType": "WebDriverException",   "stackTrace": [
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 696, in _load\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
>       "  File \"\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
>       "  File \"/var/task/scraping.py\", line 16, in \n    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver,
>   chrome_options=chrome_options)\n",
>       "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 73, in **init**\n    self.service.start()\n",
>       "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py\", line 83, in start\n    os.path.basename(self.path),
>   self.start_error_message)\n"   ] }

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda runs on linux. You have to download the linux chromedriver and the file name doesn't have .exe at the end. It should be just chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

Why arent you using the 'normal' chromedriver from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/?

On windows this works for me:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/myPath/chromedriver.exe')
```

I installed my chromedriver, unzipped it and the path where I saved it, is 'D:/myPath/' (just an example)

Comment: I did, but it didn't work again. .zip to AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Say your directory structure looks something like this:

```
project
| main.py
| chromedriver-Linux64
```

You should have the chromedriver binary at the same level as your project files. Also, change the path pointing to the chromedriver binary from `/chromedriver-Linux64.exe` to `./chromedriver-Linux64.exe`. The path you currently have looks for the binary in the root folder, rather than the current directory. The `.` means look in the directory this file is in.

Comment: I send at 'chromedriver/chromedriver-Linux64.exe' but I can not run.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Write your path something like this

> "C:\Users\arjun.bhardwaj\Downloads\drvr\chromedriver.exe

Comment: but my project must run on AWS Lambda; isn't it ridiculous?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#can use below if pip/sudo install webdriver_manager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#this below not really required if using --headless`enter code here`
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=960x900') 
# You can use the below to run
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```